# Dependency Injection with ILogger and Abstract Classes .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ilogger

I am using a repository pattern for my .NET Core project. I have a base repository:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext MyContext { get; set; }

    public RepositoryBase(DbContext context)
    {
        MyContext = context;
    }
```

}

Then I have entity specific repositories that derive from the base class. For example:

```
   public class ClientRepository : RepositoryBase<Client>, IClientRepository
{
    public ClientRepository(DbContext context)
       : base(context)
    {
    }
```

I then have a repository wrapper, which instantiates all of those entity specific repositories.

I want to give all my repositories access to my logger, which I have configured via dependency injection.  However, my logger seems to expect a type, for example

```
ILogger<ClientRepository>
```

I added the logger to the base class in the generic form, and in the entity classes I did the specific form of the ILogger. But, in the repository wrapper constructor, I now need to declare and inject all of those different types of ILoggers. And wherever the repository wrapper is constructed, I need to add all of those in as args.

Can anyone clarify the correct way to inject an ILogger and have it move 'downstream' so to speak, through abstract and derived classes?

Comment: Declare the `ILogger` object, say `_logger`, as a protected member in the base repository and use it as `this._logger` in the child repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. I don't know of any practical difference.

### Option A `ILogger`

`ILogger<T>` is an `ILogger`:

```
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
```

Your base repo can accept `ILogger`.

### Option B `ILogger<BaseClass>`

`ILogger<DerivedClass>` is also `ILogger<BaseClass>` so in your case `ILogger<ClientRepository>` is a `ILogger<RepositoryBase<Client>>`.

The base repo can accept `ILogger<RepositoryBase<Client>>`.